# sorting array in heap memory

Tags: arrays, c, heap-memory, qsort

I have to write a function to sort an array in the heap. This function should make a copy of the array, sort the copy, and return a pointer to the sorted copy.  I tried `qsort()` but I get strange output. I'm sure it has something to do with the pointer but still can't figure it out.

This is my code so far:

```
int cmpfunc(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}

int sorted_copy(int* list[], size_t s)
{
    int aList[s];
    memcpy(aList,list,s);
    printf("Array was copied successfuly to aList[] array\n\n");
    printf("Before sorting the list is: \n");

    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
        printf("%d\n", aList[i]);

    qsort(aList, s, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);
    printf("After sorting the list is: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", aList[i]);
    }
    return *aList;
}

int main()
{
    int list[10] = {4, 1, 2, 7, 3, 5, 6, 0, 8, 9};
    sorted_copy(list,sizeof(list));
    return 0;
}
```

An this the output I'm getting

```
    Array was copied successfuly to aList[] array

Before sorting the list is:
4
1
2
7
3
5
6
0
8
9
0
0
0
0
3
0
0
0
268501009
32762
4199840
0
-1407817721
32762
12846904
0
1324151619
0
8
0
176
0
6487584
0
4199972
0
4200528
0
-1434081178 
32762
After sorting the list is:
-1434081178
-1407817721
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
2
3
3
4
5
6
7
8
8
9
176
32762
32762
32762
4199840
4199972
4200528
6487584
12846904
268501009
1324151619

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.281 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: Dumping an array of pointer-to-`int` in to an array of `int` isn't a good start to whatever you're trying to do. Also, you're not actually copying to capacity anyway. The third argument to `memcpy` is a size in *bytes*; not an element count. And finally, "returning a sorted copy" is going to involve either an additional in/out parameter, a static array, or some dynamic allocation.

Comment: fix like [this](https://ideone.com/m9zdtF)

Comment: you are returning an adress of a local variable which deletes after funcion closure

Answer (score 0):

Well, the second parameter of `sorted_copy()`  must be the number of elements of array passed as first parameter, and not its `sizeof` (the size of the object in memory bytes)  I'm supposing you are using a 32 bit architecture, where an `int` is four bytes wide, and you are passing `40` as the array number of elements, not `10` which is the actual number of cells in the array.

Change

```
int main()
{
    /* you don't need to specify the number of elements to declare
     * the array if you are using an initializer that fully populates
     * the array elements */
    int list[10] = {4, 1, 2, 7, 3, 5, 6, 0, 8, 9};
    sorted_copy(list,sizeof(list)); /* sizeof gives you the array 
                                     * size in bytes, not in number 
                                     * of elements */
    return 0;
}
```

into

```
int main()
{
    int list[] = {4, 1, 2, 7, 3, 5, 6, 0, 8, 9};
    sorted_copy(list, sizeof list / sizeof list[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

and you'll get the correct result.